# Unable to add the Remote URL https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment

Tags: future, remote-site-settings

Hi am attempting Challenge2  : Synchronize Salesforce data with an external system of the Apex Specialist Superbadge

but unable to add the below url to Remote Site settings

https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment

It saves as https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com - donot know why ?

Can someone help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Remote Site "URL" simply specifies the protocol (http/https) and server domain. The path, query parameters, and payload (body) is specified in the code that calls the endpoint, not in the Remote Site setting itself. Salesforce automatically removes any path or query string information, since it does not restrict by path, only by domain.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox...looks like you are spot on !